# How to send data through jQuery AJAX and retrieve using JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to send this variable `fid` to my JSP page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=' + api_key,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'testing'
}).error(function() {
    console.log('error')
}).done(function(response) {
    fid = response.genres[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.genres.length)].id;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/' + fid + '/movies?api_key=' + api_key,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'testing'
    }).error(function() {
        console.log('error')
    }).done(function(response) {
        k = Math.floor(Math.random() * response.results.length);
        $('#search_results').append(
            '<img id="rimg" style="height:300px;width:300px;"src="' +
            images_uri + response.results[k].poster_path +
            '" alt="image not available"></img>'
        );
        $('#d2').append('<h2 id="h2">' + response.results[k].title + '</h2>');
    });
});
});
```

Comment: are u using script code in jsp?

Comment: What data you want to send and where?

Comment: just call this function from your jsp code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a parameter from AJAX to JSP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223583/passing-a-parameter-from-ajax-to-jsp-page)